# How to convert memory adresses to string values in map variable using JSON Unmarshal?

Tags: json, go

I am using a map type variable to serialize my JSON POST response from an API and work with it in Go.

Using string for the keys and []*json.RawMessage array as the type for the values in the map.

"act" and "key" are function parameters that populate the http.PostForm. This is an isolated function that is called from main()

Here is the relevant code:

```
resp, err := http.PostForm(api, url.Values{"API": {key}, "action": {act}})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("AN ERROR OCCURED!")
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer func(Body io.ReadCloser) {
    err := Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}(resp.Body)
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var objmap map[string][]*json.RawMessage
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &objmap)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(objmap)
```

Here is what I receive within my zsh terminal as output :

map[success:[0xc00000e060 0xc00000e078 0xc00000e090]]

Unmarshal is clearly able to map the key "success" with what appears to be memory address representation of the array value, but the array value itself (which is an array of nested objects) is not shown.

There does not seem to be any error with the Unmarshal to the pointer variable itself. The API returns a single JSON object, with a key "success" and an array as a value with nested objects. My goal is to map each nested value and be able to parse it.

Is there another step that needs to be completed in order to access the values nested within the array? How do I convert these memory addresses into the actual values they appear to represent. Does JSON Unmarshal not support mapping of JSON arrays, only objects?

Comment: I do not need the entire JSON response. Only want the parsed data for displaying to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does JSON Unmarshal not support mapping of JSON arrays, only objects?

The encoding/json Unmarshal function supports all JSON entities including arrays. The [Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) documentation describes how JSON entities are mapped to Go values.

The question decodes the JSON to a map of slices of pointers to json.RawMessage. The printed output shows the slice of pointers.

Use the dereference operator `*` to dereference the pointers in the slice:

```
for k, values := range objmap {
    for _, v := range values {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, *v) // note the * on this line
    }
}
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A_7mv-E-wkY).

A `json.RawMessage` is a slice of bytes take directly from the JSON document. You must unmarshal again to get Go values.  Use a string [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a `json.RawMessage` to a `string`:

```
for k, values := range objmap {
    for _, v := range values {
        s := string(*v) // * dereferences pointer, string() converts to string
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, s)
    }
}
```

The pointers are not needed. Simplify the code like this:

```
var objmap map[string][]json.RawMessage // * removed on this line
err := json.Unmarshal(body, &objmap)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(objmap)
for k, values := range objmap {
    for _, v := range values {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, v) // ... and this line
    }
}
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N0uz2FxPLwo).